# Интерпретировать вводимую строку как название функции

Tags: python, функции

Написать калькулятор с использованием замыканий.                       Калькулятор должен включать в себя все базовые математические                          операции, а также квадратный корень и кубический корень чисел

```
def calculator(funс, a, b):
    return funс(a, b)

def addition(a, b):
    return a + b

def deduction(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiplication(a, b):
    return a * b

def division(a, b):
    return a / b

def squadruple(a, b):
    return a ** b

def extractiong(a, b):
    return a ** (1 / b)

user_operetion = input("Enter operetion (1.addition, 2.deduction, 3.multiplication, 4.division, 5.squadruple, 6.extractiong): ")
a = int(input("Enter numer 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter numer 2: "))
calculator(user_operetion, a, b)
```

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+eval)

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать словарь, в котором ключами будут названия функций, а значениями - сами функции. При вводе названия функции, вызовем ее из словаря, а при необходимости можно сразу передать в неё параметры.

```
def func1(param):
    return param

def func2():
    return "Это функция 2"

def func3():
    return "Это функция 3"

# Создаем словарь с функциями
function_dict = {
    'func1': func1,
    'func2': func2,
    'func3': func3
}
param = "user_operetion"
result = function_dict['func1'](param)
print(result)  # Выведет: "user_operetion"

result = function_dict['func2']()
print(result)  # Выведет: "Это функция 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение в лоб:

```
import sys
def calculator(funс, a, b):
    return funс(a, b)

def addition(a, b):
    return a + b

def deduction(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiplication(a, b):
    return a * b

def division(a, b):
    return a / b

def squadruple(a, b):
    return a ** b

def extractiong(a, b):
    return a ** (1 / b)

user_operetion = input("Enter operetion (1.addition, 2.deduction, 3.multiplication, 4.division, 5.squadruple, 6.extractiong): ")
try:
    locals()[user_operetion](1,2)
except KeyError:
    print('Введена не функция!')
    sys.exit()
a = int(input("Enter numer 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter numer 2: "))
calculator(user_operetion, int(a), int(b))
```

Вызываем функцию с названием из строки методом `locals()`, при вводе неверных данных (то есть при возникновении ошибки `KeyError` используем `sys.exit()` для завершения работы программы.

---

Ну или через `eval()`, но это [опасный](https://habr.com/ru/articles/221937/) метод:

```
user_operetion = input("Enter operetion (1.addition, 2.deduction, 3.multiplication, 4.division, 5.squadruple, 6.extractiong): ")
try:
    eval(f'{user_operetion}(1,2)')
except NameError:
    print('Введена не функция!')
    sys.exit()
a = int(input("Enter numer 1: "))
b = int(input("Enter numer 2: "))
calculator(user_operetion, int(a), int(b))
```